# Checking a user's password on Ldap with dynamic dn in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, ldap

With sf3 
symfony 3 password can be checked but with a static dn

```
dn_string: 'uid={username},dc=example,dc=com'
```

So I created my own UserAuthenticationProvider class

But now I don't know how to declare it in my security.yml ?

**security.yml**

```
  providers:

    your_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AcSecurityBundle:User
            property: username
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

   secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: your_db_provider
        form_login:
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            use_referer: true
        form_login_ldap:
            service: ldap
            use_referer: true
        logout: true
```

**AcSecurityBundle/AcUserAuthenticationProvider.php**

class AcUserAuthenticationProvider extends UserAuthenticationProvider
{

```
function checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
{
    $username = $token->getUsername();
    $password = $token->getCredentials();

    if ('' === $password) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password must not be empty.');
    }

    try {
        $query = "(sAMAccountName=$username)";

        $search_dn = "CN=app,OU=apps,DC=domain,DC=be";
        $search_password = "mdp";
        $this->ldap->bind($search_dn, $search_password);

        $t = $this->ldap->query("OU=At,OU=user,DC=domain,DC=be", $query);

        $entry = $t->execute();

        if ($entry->count() > 0) {
            $dn = $entry[0]->getDn();
        }

        $this->ldap->bind($dn, $password);
    } catch (ConnectionException $e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password is invalid.');
    }
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: I would rethink that implementation when I read it correctly. First you are hardwiring the attribute "sAMAccountName" here for authentication. That makes your authentication provider usable ONLY with an AD-Backend. Second, what happens, when $entry->count() is more than one?

Comment: Yes I have a AD-Backend. My code works. This is not the worries.
what I want is to declare my authenfication provider so that symfony uses one instead of his own (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/LdapBindAuthenticationProvider.php)

Comment: Why do you want to roll your own implementation? What's not working with the default symphony provider?

Answer (score 1):

> Since Symfony 3.1 Symfony uses a new ldap provider 
>   Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap

**Provider Example:**

```
services:

app.ldap:
    class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
    factory: [ 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap', 'create']
    arguments:
        - ext_ldap
        - host: srv-host
          #debug: true
```

> The string associated to the adapter you wish to use.
>  Only one is
>   supported for now, which is ext_ldap.
>   [New Ldap provider by Symfony, explained.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19008#issuecomment-224937692)

**Security Provider Example:**

```
providers:
    #webservice_provider:
        #id: app.webservice_user_provider
    company_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: app.ldap
            base_dn: DC=example, DC=local
            search_dn: "CN=AdminName,OU=YourAdminGroup,DC=example,DC=LOCAL"
            search_password: 'AdminPass'
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
```

> Now you are allowed to look in your ldap system. 
>  If you set your
>   form_login_ldap right, your users can authenticate via your form

**Security form_login_ldap Example:**

```
form_login_ldap:
   provider: company_ldap
   service: app.ldap #system/provider your user authenticate to
   dn_string: '{username}@example.local'
   csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
   check_path: /login_check #make sure the check is behind the firewall
   login_path: /login #make sure login IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

   logout:       
      path:   /logout  #logout path
      target: /login   #after logout redirect to login
   anonymous:    true
```

**Access_control/firewall Example:**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER } #all pages require user to be logged in
```

Now you have your dynamic ldap login form.
[Symfony login form setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

Hope this helps you. Took me 8 days to figure this out by myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help
But your method does not solve my problem: it's always a static dn
After the existence of the user has been loaded (Component / Security / Core / User / LdapUserProvider.php) successfully
Sf checks the login password (Component / Security / Core / Authentication / Provider / LdapBindAuthenticationProvider.php) with a simple bind

But it's cool that you have found the right config to use the undepreciated ldap client class ;-)

Comment: Hi @Jsenechal , so what is the solution ? Because i'm interested about your solution

Comment: Hi @Tweakdev here is a working solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611281/symfony-authenticate-with-local-sql-or-ldap/68613308#68613308

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of the above. You can use the DN string as:

`dn_string: '{username}'`

That's actually the default value [according to the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/ldap.html#dn-string).This will work because AD supports several bind methods in addition to a full DN (such as the sAMAccountName or UPN).

Comment: I just want to emphasize that this ONLY works with AD. So technically it's not an LDAP-question!

Comment: @heiglandreas He has clearly stated that this is for an AD environment. If this is for a corporate application and they're using an AD backend, then there is no problem with using some AD specific functionality.

Comment: It's tagged LDAP when it should be Active-Directory… That's all I'm saying.

Comment: It's samba4...

I tried with a simple bind username, password but it does not work
How to override : vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/‌​Authentication/Provi‌​der/LdapBindAuthenti‌​cationProvider.php
?

Comment: Hmmm...I would think Samba would have the same bind options. Does the user's UPN work for the bind? (ie. `username@domain.local`)?